# How can I extract and format HTML found in a div tag, using Perl?

Tags: html, perl

#### Note:

- Using [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://lwp.interglacial.com/ch09_02.htm) or other suitable method

#### Question:

- Using Perl with [LWP](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2002/08/20/perlandlwp.html), for the following HTML, how to **search** for the literal string **whatever** between the start tag and end tag **div** and then **get** all text between the aforementioned start and end tag, while **adhering** to formatting text tags

  ```
  <div id="foo" class="blah">
  <tt>
  test
  <br>test 
  <br>whatever
  <br>test
  </div>
  ```

To print to STDOUT:

```
test
test
whatever
test
```

Comment: Where does 'test123' come from?

Comment: OK. But where does 'testwhatever' come from?

Comment: @Manni: so sorry! Silly typo... :-(. Just changed

Comment: Is this the same problem your trying to solve with your very similar question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945258/how-can-i-render-html-as-text-using-perl-as-lynx-does ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my @elms = $tree->look_down(
  _tag => "div",
  sub { $_[0]->as_text =~ /whatever/ },
);

for my $elm (@elms) {
  print $elm->as_trimmed_text;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$node->find_by_attribute(attribute, value) and $node->as_text()
```

http://lwp.interglacial.com/ch09_03.htm

Comment: @el-pescado: thanks, but I'd like to search for text between a specified start and end tag first, before obtaining the text accordingly...

Comment: @Aaron: I believe that El-pescado's answer tells you (implicitly) how to do what you want. `HTML::Element` gives you `find_by_attribute` and `find_by_tag` methods that should get you there.